# C# Wpf Binding to Collection of Userdefined Class not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Currently i have an ObservableCollection of MyClass in my Viewmodel. I use the getter of this Collection to fill it from an other Datasource. I can now Display this Data in a Window(Grid) and the correct Data is shown, but when i change the Data the set is not fired(I think it is because not the Collection is changed, only a Element in the Collection). Should i create a Property for every Property of MyClass, so i can react to the changes of a single Value, the Questions i ask myself are:

- How do i know what Element is selected at the moment
- How to fill the Collection correct when i have a binding to every single item

I also thought of a Event when my Collection is changed, but i am not sure how to implement it right.

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass<string>> SelectedParams
{
  get
  {
    //Fill the Collection
  }
  set
  {
    //I think here i want to react to changed Textboxvalues in my View
  }
}
 public class MyClass<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private T _curValue;
   private string _value1;
   private string _value2;

   public string Value1
   {
     get
     {
       return _value1;
     }
     set
     {
       if (_value1 != value)
       {
         _value1 = value;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value1)));
       }
     }
   }
   public string Value2
   {
     get
     {
       return _value2;
     }
     set
     {
       if (_value2 != value)
       {
         _value2 = value;
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value2)));
       }
     }
   }
   public T curValue
   {
     get
     {
       return _curValue;
     }
     set
     {
       _curValue = value;
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(curValue)));
     }
   }

   public MyClass()
   {
   }
   public MyClass(string val1, string val2, T curVal)
   {
     Value1 = val1;
     Value2 = val2;
     curValue = curVal;
   }
 }
```

The xaml Code looks something like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedParams}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding Value1}"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding Value2}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding curValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Edit1: Changed MyClass to INotifyPropertyChanged now the Collection changes internal Values but the Setter is still not called on change of a Value

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [INotifyPropertChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for MyClass and raise the PropertyChanged in setter to notify UI that the property value changed.

Comment: Thx for answer, changed the code, now the Collection changes internal values but the setter of the Observable Collection is still not fired

Comment: If you are creating new collection, than you need to do the same thing with the collection's property. Otherwise UI will not be notified about changes and will use old collection as a data source.

Comment: I think i know what you mean but i am not sure how to implement it, can you give me a hint or a code example?

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertChanged interface also for the class in which defined your collection and fire the event on setter method of the collection's property.

Comment: Sry to ask one more time.
My Class where the collection is defined implements the INotifyPropertychanged. The setter Method of the Collection is never called so it does not matter if i fire the event there. I tried to listen to the CollectionChanged event but it also only gets fired with the NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add when i fill the Collection but never when i change a value.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are updating the Collection?

Comment: Do you always return a new collection from getter method? If yes, then it will not work. You need to store collection and update the content when you need.

Comment: ok solved the problem, added an eventhandler for every element i add to the collection everytime i add an element to the collection. the eventhandler stores the value

thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

> How do i know what Element is selected at the moment

If you want support for item selection you have to use an other control. ItemsControl does not support selection.

Use ListView for example. Bind ItemsSource and SelectedItem to your class. Now every time you click on an item, SelectedValue is updated. And if you change SelectedValue from code the UI updates the selected item in the list. You can also bind other controls to SelectedValue like I did with the TextBlock outside the ListView.

**View**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item1}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="=" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item2}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="Selected:" Background="DarkGray" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedValue.Item1, Mode=OneWay}" Background="DarkGray" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

**Data**

```
public class ListViewBindingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Tuple<string,int> _selectedValue;

    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,int>> Values { get; }

    public Tuple<string, int> SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _selectedValue = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedValue)));
        }
    }

    public ListViewBindingViewModel()
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, int>> {Tuple.Create("Dog", 3), Tuple.Create("Cat", 5), Tuple.Create("Rat",1)};
    }

}
```